# Calculate the curve length of the $ x\cos x $ function and the straight lines $ x = \frac{\pi}{2} $ and $ y = 0 $

Tags: calculus

I want to calculate the area  of the $ x\cos x $ function and the straight lines $ x = \frac{\pi}{2} $ and $ y = 0 $

I have got the area of the curve is given by $A=\int_{a}^{b}2\pi f(x)\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx$

$$A=\int_{a}^{b}2\pi f(x)\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}2\pi x\cos x\sqrt{1+(\cos x- \sin x)^2}dx$$
$$A=\int_{0}^{\pi}2\pi x\cos x\sqrt{2+\sin 2x}dx$$

But I do not know if must to use integral by parts or maby sustitution.

Comment: How did you get the limits of integral?

Comment: The formula you have is the one of the lateral surface of the solid of revolution. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution under "Area"

Comment: Yes I know but how can I computethe integral?

Answer (score 0):

The [length of the curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating) given by the graph of a differentiable function $f$ between $a$ and $b$ is
$$\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx.$$ 
The formula that you are using gives the [area of a surface of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution#Area_formula).

I guess you would like to compute the area of the plane region bounded by the graph of $f(x)=x\cos(x)$  and the straight lines $ x = \frac{\pi}{2} $ and $ y = 0 $. This area is equal to
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\cos(x) dx$$ 
which, by the way, is much more simpler (use integration by parts).

Comment: But what about the area?

Comment: @SHB See my edited answer.